# Predicate logic digraph relations

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, relations, first-order-logic

Let $X$ be the set ${\{a,b,d,e,f}\}$, and let $R$ be the relation ${\{(a,a),(a,d),(a,e),(b,b),(b,c),(c,c),(c,b),(d,d_, (d,e),(e,e)}\}$.

Now, I'm trying to find a definable subset of $X$ which satisfies $\exists u(R(u,v) \land u \neq v)$.

I have no idea what this formula means, though; I know $R(u,v)$ means that $u$ and $v$ are related; thus there is a link from $u$ to $v$ on the directed graph but what does $R(u,v) \land u$ even mean?

Comment: The only interpretation that makes sense to me is that $\wedge$ is the *AND* operator.  That you are told to find a subrelation such that there is at least one element which is related to something that it is not.  That is to say, $R(u,v)\wedge u$ does not mean anything, but $R(u,v) \wedge (u\neq v)$ does.

Comment: In later, possibly more complicated questions, you might be asked to look into the properties of [meets and joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) in a lattice order which also use the symbols $\wedge$ and $\vee$ respectively, however since $R(u,v)$ is not an element of the relation but rather a truth value, this does not make sense in this context for $\wedge$ to represent the meet operator.

Comment: I mean it is $\exists u(R(u,v) \land (u \neq v))$

Answer (score 1):

I believe it asks to find the subset consisting of all elements $v$ such that $\exists u(R(u,v) \land u \neq v)$

So, if we call that subset $S$, we can define $S$ as: $S = \{ v \in X | \exists u (R(u,v) \land u \not = v \}$

In other words: find all element such that some *different* element is related to it.

Thus, for example, $d \in S$, since $a$ is related to it, i.e. $(a,d) \in R$.

But nothing is related to $a$ other than $a$ itself, and that is not different from $a$, so $a \not \in S$.